# In what case would water attack the least substituted carbon in an oxymercuration–demercuration reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, c-c-addition

I understand that oxymercuration–demercuration is textbook Markovnikov. However, in a case like this, where the $\ce{OH}$ is formed on the least substituted carbon (secondary) rather than the most substituted (tertiary because of the methyl group), what could be the explanation?

I thought that $\ce{H2O}$ always attacks the most substituted carbon which is why $\ce{OH}$ forms there.

[image: methyl tiglate to methyl 3‐hydroxy‐2‐methylbutanoate via 1. Hg(OAc)2, H2O/THF; 2. NaBH4]

Comment: This is not a simple alkene. The presence of the ester makes a big difference

Comment: So would this be an example on one of the exceptions for oxymercuration-demercuration where Markovnikov doesn't apply? Because of the presence of an ester?

Comment: Think about which carbocation is more stable in this case: the one on the more substituted carbon or the one on the less substituted carbon. Hint: the ester is an Electron Withdrawing group.

Comment: Oh ok! I think it'd be because the tertiary carbon is closer to the ether, and the ether has the o=c which is an electron withdrawing group. So it will cause a withdrawing effect, rendering a bond there to be unfavourable? It would be more favourable in this case for the OH to be formed on the secondary carbon...